# YouTube API Quota is taking over 3 weeks, is this normal?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, quota

I have requested a quota increase on the YouTube Data API.

I am getting the impression I’m being given the run around or no one inside of Google actually works on this.

I requested a quota increase over 3 weeks ago, and every time I email them, I get a very generic:

> We understand your concern about the Quota. As informed earlier your request is being reviewed by our Quality Compliance Team. Their review takes longer time and hence is causing the delay. Any update that we receive from them will be shared with you immediately.

But it’s been 3 weeks.

Has anybody else had the same experience? If so, how long did it take to get approved?

Comment: According to the experience of the users of this forum, the answer is *yes*. In cases, some of them reported receiving a reply from Google after a month (or even much more) from issuing their application.

Comment: It took me more then three months 

Comment: @DalmTo OMG that's crazy